# Why doesn't "jobs" show a ssh tunnel I opened in the background?

Tags: ssh, bash, process

I'm starting a ssh tunnel like this:

```
ssh -f -N $PORT:127.0.0.1:$port example.com
```

the `-f` puts ssh into the background, which is what I want. This works, since there is a SSH tunnel set up. But if I use `jobs` I can't see the ssh connection listed. How come?

Comment: Please include your platform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you didn't use bash to send it into the background. `jobs` only reports on processes that bash itself has sent to the background; it was ssh itself that "daemonized" it, as ericslaw said. To get jobs to report it, you'd do:

```
ssh -N $PORT:127.0.0.1:$port example.com &
```

Answer (score 5):

The ssh process likely daemonized, disconnecting from the shell.
You can think of it like this (but possibly not in this order):

The 'ssh' process you launched actually closed all it's file descriptors (stdin,stdout,stderr), disconnected from the tty, and forked another child ssh.
 then called exit on itself.  This orphaned the child process and the original ssh process actually 'completes'.

As a result, the original ssh process is complete and the orphaned process is no longer a 'child' of your shell.

Use 'ps -ef' or 'ps -fu$USER' instead to see the ssh process you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

You can see what program is listening on the `port` using command:

```
lsof -i :port
```

It will give you ssh pid.